# How is an infrared image represented in python?

Tags: python, opencv, infrared

If I connect an IR camera to my laptop and capture frames from that video stream with openCV, exactly what format would that frame be stored as?
Can it be stored as an atypical 3 channel rgb numpy array?

Comment: probably it will be single channel ingensity. You can use color maps to generate color from single channel. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4.13.7/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html

Comment: That depends on the IR camera, most of them is a 1 channel 16 bits image... this may vary depending on the camera. I would recommend to save it as a 16 bit 1 channel png image, to avoid loosing data. If you are only doing it for visualization only, then apply a color map as @Micka suggests.

Comment: Not sure what you are getting at with your question, but yes, you *can* store it as an atypical 3 channel RGB numpy array if you really want to - it's just not very efficient in terms of space as the red, green and blue channels will be identical for a grey image so you are storing 3 identical channels unnecessarily when a single one would suffice.